# why -moz-user-modify not working in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, contenteditable

editable div inside that i have input element in CKEditor

`<div contenteditable="false">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Default Value" contenteditable="true" 
value=""></div>‍`

input element by default inside CKEditor is not editable ,when i used this styles

```
-webkit-user-modify:intial;
-moz-user-modify:intial;
```

Works fine in chrome but not working in Firefox .
I read about the property from following [blog](https://paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-properties/user-modified.php), even the example seems to not working in firefox .

Answer (score -1):

I think you can have problems with the compatibility of this property. You can see more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify